# Turkish citizen, UK resident, business travel to Italy and Germany

Tags: germany, italy, uk-residents, turkish-citizens

I am an indefinite leave holder in the UK, permanently settled. I work in the UK. I only hold a Turkish passport though.

I need to do a short business trip to Italy and then Germany. I have a 2 year multi visit Schengen tourist visa which I know won't be valid for this purpose.

Would I need to individually get business visas from Italian consulate and German consulate for my trips?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a 2 year multi visit Schengen tourist visa which I know won't be valid for this purpose.

A business visa is not separate from a tourist visa, and what you have is a *uniform* visa. The categories are used by consulates to help you with what documents they want from you, depending on the purpose of your **first** stay.

**If you have already used the first entry** of the visa and that you have followed the rules (no overstay), you are free to use it for any purpose covered under the short-stay visa rules for the country you want to visit while making sure to bring along all the needed paperwork

---

If your visa is unused, this is trickier :

Please read about the [main destination](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/98106/118049) concept before reading below :

- If the country that originally issued your 2-year multi-entry visa, is still the main destination, you will have no issue with using that visa
- If this is not your main destination, you need to apply for a new visa

> Would I need to individually get business visas from Italian consulate and German consulate for my trips?

No, you need to apply at the consulate of your main destination, and mention both trips

Comment: Wow, are you sure about this? My understanding has always been that I can only enter for tourism. I have already used that one like 10 times. So if I have all the proving documents at the border, are you implying I could actually enter for business purpose with a multi-visit 2 year "tourist" Schengen visa?

Comment: @thephysicsguy Absolutely yes, a Schengen short-stay uniform visa, is, as its name suggests, *uniform* and covers all the activities allowed under it. Once the first entry is used, you are free to use it for any Schengen state and for any allowed purpose. If you look at your visa sticker, the purpose, if even mentioned, is in the "remarks" non-standard field, not in any standard field.

Comment: Okay I never knew, thank you so much for this info! Such a shame I haven't properly checked before.